# On which heaven was Idris located on the night of Mi’raaj?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, contradiction

Assalamu alaikum

Why contradict comes between two sahih hadiths? Particularly sahih al bukhari 7517 and 3207 contradict about prophet idris stayed on which heaven? Which one is correct?? How authentic Hadith become contradict with each other??

sahih al bukhari 7517

> Idris on the second Heaven
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/142

sahih al bukhari 3207

> Then we ascended to the 4th heaven and again the same questions and answers were exchanged as in the previous heavens. There I met Idris
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite possible for a sahih hadith to contradict with another in such trivial matters. This can happen due to a mistake by the transmitter, as they are not infallible. Some scholars have preferred the view that Idris (عليه السلام) was on the fourth heaven as transmitted by other chains for example the ones through [Qatada](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/18) and [Thabit](https://sunnah.com/muslim:162a) are in agreement with each other and so are likely to be correct.

It is also possible to reconcile them. The view of some is that Isra’ and Mi’raaj happened two (or even more times), one of them in a dream and one physically. So it is possible that the location of the prophets was different in the two incidents.

Reference:

- [Tafsir Qurtubi](https://shamela.ws/book/20855/4256)

  > . قلت: ووقع في البخاري عن شريك بن عبد الله بن أبي نمر قال سمعت أنس بن
  > مالك يقول: ليلة أسري برسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم من مسجد الكعبة،
  > الحديث وفيه: كل سماء فيها أنبياء- قد سماهم- منهم إدريس في الثانية.
  >
  > وهو وهم، والصحيح أنه في السماء الرابعة، كذلك رواه ثابت البناني عن أنس
  > بن مالك عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم، ذكره مسلم في الصحيح. وروى مالك بن
  > صعصعة قال قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: (لما عرج بي إلى السماء أتيت
  > على إدريس في السماء الرابعة). خرجه مسلم أيضا
- [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/7743#p1) also see [here](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3934#p1)

  > وقد قدمت في شرحه أن الأكثر وافقوا قتادة وسياقه يدل على رجحان روايته فإنه ضبط اسم كل نبي والسماء التي هو فيها ووافقه ثابت عن أنس وجماعة ذكرتهم هناك فهو المعتمد لكن إن قلنا إن القصة تعددت فلا ترجيح ولا إشكال

Comment: Pls Can you translate the above arabic text in your comment??